# Browse XML child

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have a little problem with reading an XML file on C#.
This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<SITES>
    <SITE>
        <ERROR_COUNTER>0</ERROR_COUNTER>
        <PROD>0</PROD>
        <LOGINFO>
            <URL>http://site1.com/login</URL>
            <LOGIN>login</LOGIN>
            <PASSWORD>pass</PASSWORD>
            <DELAYMAX>20</DELAYMAX>
        </LOGINFO>
        <EMAIL>
            <TO>dsds@dee.com, dsdsddd@dee.com,dsdds@dee.com</TO>
            <SUBJECT></SUBJECT>
            <BODY></BODY>
            <PATH></PATH>
        </EMAIL>
        <TESTS>
            <TEST>
                <URL>http://site1.com/settings</URL>
                <DELAYMAX>5</DELAYMAX>
            </TEST>
            <TEST>
                <URL>http://site1.com/faq</URL>
                <DELAYMAX>5</DELAYMAX>
            </TEST>
            <TEST>
                <URL>http://site1.com/download-faq-pdf</URL>
                <DELAYMAX>5</DELAYMAX>
            </TEST>
        </TESTS>
    </SITE>
    <SITE>
        <ERROR_COUNTER>0</ERROR_COUNTER>
        <PROD>0</PROD>
        <LOGINFO>
            <URL>http://site2.com/login</URL>
            <LOGIN>login2</LOGIN>
            <PASSWORD>pass2</PASSWORD>
            <DELAYMAX>20</DELAYMAX>
        </LOGINFO>
        <EMAIL>
            <TO>dsds@dee.com, dsdsddd@dee.com,dsdds@dee.com</TO>
            <SUBJECT></SUBJECT>
            <BODY></BODY>
            <PATH></PATH>
        </EMAIL>
        <TESTS>
            <TEST>
                <URL>http://site2.com/settings</URL>
                <DELAYMAX>5</DELAYMAX>
            </TEST>
            <TEST>
                <URL>http://site2.com/faq</URL>
                <DELAYMAX>5</DELAYMAX>
            </TEST>
            <TEST>
                <URL>http://site2.com/download-faq-pdf</URL>
                <DELAYMAX>5</DELAYMAX>
            </TEST>
        </TESTS>
    </SITE>
</SITES>
```

So I would like to be able, in C#, to browse the list of my sites (I can have several dozen of them), for that, I did this:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(@"D:\REM\config.xml");
    foreach (XmlElement ndSites in xml.SelectNodes("SITES/SITE"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ndSites.GetElementsByTagName("ERROR_COUNTER"));
    }
```

But once I have done this, I don't know how to access my children's values, let alone how to make a second loop on my TESTS, and then access each child TEST and retrieve my URLs.

My goal is being to retrieve for each website the connection information in LOGINFO, then the URLs in TESTS, TEST and for all the SITES present.

I've tried a lot of things, but I haven't found anything that matches what I need.

If someone could help me.

EDIT : This is my class for deserialize the code C#

```
class XMLParser
{
    public XMLParser() { }
    public List<Site> readXML(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
        Test test;

        List<Site> sites = new List<Site>();
        Site site;

        //List<url>;
        foreach (XmlElement ndSites in xml.SelectNodes("SITES/SITE"))
        {
            int idSite = int.Parse(ndSites.Attributes[0].Value);
            site = new Site();
            int prod = int.Parse(ndSites["PROD"].InnerText);
            int error = 0;
            int max = 3;

            foreach (XmlElement ndError in ndSites.SelectNodes("/ERROR"))
            {
                error = int.Parse(ndError["COUNTER"].InnerText);
                max = int.Parse(ndError["MAX"].InnerText);
            }
            foreach (XmlElement ndLogin in ndSites.SelectNodes("LOGINFO"))
            {
                site = new Site(idSite, ndLogin["URL"].InnerText, ndLogin["LOGIN"].InnerText, ndLogin["PASSWORD"].InnerText, error, prod, max);
            }

            foreach (XmlElement ndTests in ndSites.SelectNodes("TESTS/TEST"))
            {
                test = new Test(ndTests["URL"].InnerText, int.Parse(ndTests["DELAYMAX"].InnerText));
                tests.Add(test);
            }
            site.lstTest = tests;
            sites.Add(site);
        }
        return sites;
    }
```

But my i have another problem, when i use my Site object, o have six elements, all the URLs of my site 1 and all the url of my site 2.

For exemple with my XML file above, i would therefore have two Test objects of six elements

Comment: I would probably create a class that models the xml and [deserialize the xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object). Then you can access everything as object properties.

Comment: I absolutely don't know how to do it, we how it works, I'll look, but it's not possible to do this natively in XML ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can do it with xml but it would be a lot more mess. If you copy this xml and go to Visual Studio, create a new .cs file, choose Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes it will generate the classes for you. However it will make some dumb names and data types that you might want to clean up.

Comment: I saw that it was possible to copy and generate the class directly, but I am on visual studio 2010, I don't have the options

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. Give this a try: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well! :)

Comment: GoodLock dude. if my answer was true, you can mark that is true.

Answer (score 5):

Simply you can work with reference value, your code if true, but I completed well.

when you want to work with an `xml` code, you have to know that structure as well.now lock this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"D:\REM\config.xml");
foreach (XmlElement ndSites in xml.SelectNodes("your node"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ndSites.GetElementsByTagName("your node"));
}
```

This method, `GetElementsByTagName()` get All `xml` section that you want and you can work with that like:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"D:\REM\config.xml");
foreach (XmlElement ndSites in xml.SelectNodes("your node"))
{
    var xmlNode = ndSites.GetElementsByTagName("your node");
    if(xmlNode != null && xmlNode.contain("your node that you want"))
    {
        foreach(var item in xmlNode.GetElementByTagName(your node that you want))
        {
             console.write(item.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Fore more information, it is good that visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Its my honore, Indeed you can work with attribute method that help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you can do something like this:

```
var MiXMLD = new XmlDocument();

MiXMLD.Load(@"C:\path\MiXML.xml");

if (!(MiXMLD == null))
{
    XmlElement mXMLERaiz = MiXMLD.DocumentElement;

    foreach (XmlNode mXMLN in mXMLERaiz.ChildNodes)
    {
        // if type is <SITE>
        if ((mXMLN.Name == "SITE"))
        {
            //In this point you can see the attributes
            if ((mXMLN.Attributes.Count > 0))
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute mAtr in mXMLN.Attributes)
                {
                    if ((mAtr.Name == "Exalmple"))
                    {
                        var attr = mAtr.Value;
                    }
                    else if ((mAtr.Name == "Example"))
                    {
                        var attr = mAtr.Value;
                    }

                }

            }

            // first node child of element of <parent>
            // you already know the type <Type>
            XmlElement mXMLchild = (XmlElement)mXMLN.FirstChild;

            // aniway check the Type
            if ((mXMLchild.Name == "Type"))
            {
                var mChild = mXMLchild.FirstChild.Value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Of course you have to read every element.

Answer (score 1):

I probably missunderstand what is your problem. Just store your xml data in business class like

```
public class Site
{
    public int ErrorCounter { get; set; }
    public LogInfo LogInfos  { get; set; }
    public Email Email { get; set; }
    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; } = new List<Test>();
}
```

You unserialize your xml inside a list of your class, with the same way you already do. Then you can access all your data

```
List<Site> siteList = new List<Site>();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"D:\REM\config.xml");
foreach (XmlElement ndSites in xml.SelectNodes("SITES/SITE"))
{
    siteList.ErrorCounter = int.Parse(ndSites["ERROR_COUNTER"].innerText); // You should handle the potential parse error expression
    /** do it for all you need */


    foreach (XmlElement ndTests in ndSites.SelectNodes("TESTS/TEST"))
    {
       Test currentTest = new Test();
       /** Fill it **/
       siteList.Tests.add(currentTest);
    }
}
```

Something about that, i don't have ide for test. 
Hope it was your question

Comment: I managed to generate my class to deserialize the xml, but I'm trying to understand how to make it work xD (I edited my code)

Comment: siteList.ErrorCounter = ndSites.GetElementsByTagName("ERROR_COUNTER")); <---- It doesn't work ><

Comment: I will take a computer with an IDE and edit my answer in few minuts. I just based my code on what you wrote in first place.

Comment: Answer edited. I think you were just looking about how to access your data. xml["TAG NAME"].InnerXml (with tags remaining) || xml["TAG NAME"].innerText (for just the text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these Wrappers. Load the XML and put it into the the Wrapper.

```
public class TestsXmlWrapper
{
    private XmlDocument _xml;
    public TestsXmlWrapper(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        _xml = xml;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Site> Sites
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (XmlElement site in _xml.SelectNodes("SITES/SITE"))
            {
                yield return new Site(site);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Site
{
    private XmlElement _site;
    public Site(XmlElement site)
    {
        _site = site;
    }

    public String ErrorCount => _site.SelectSingleNode("ERROR_COUNTER")?.InnerText;
    public String LoginUrl => _site.SelectSingleNode("LOGINFO/URL")?.InnerText;
    public String Username => _site.SelectSingleNode("LOGINFO/LOGIN")?.InnerText;
    public String Password => _site.SelectSingleNode("LOGINFO/PASSWORD")?.InnerText;
    public IEnumerable<Test> Test
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (XmlElement test in _site.SelectNodes("TESTS/TEST"))
            {
                yield return new Test(test);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private XmlElement _test;
    public Test(XmlElement test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }
    public String Url => _test.SelectSingleNode("URL")?.InnerText;
}
...the same for email
```